# Where to initialize variables in Stencil

Tags: javascript, typescript, stenciljs

I have just started Stencil, and I was wondering what was a good practise for initizializing variables.
As I see it, I have 3 possibilities:

1)    `@State() private page: Boolean = true;`

2)

```
constructor() {
    this.page = true
}
```

3)

```
componentWillLoad() {
    this.page = true;
}
```

What's the best way to do it ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first two result in the same compiled code. But I'm also curious if the third could have any advantages or disadvantages.

Comment: For code readability, I prefer initializing at declaration (#1), and generally I think initialization of default values should be done as "early" as possible. The various steps in the lifecycle will provide access to other things about the component, so that's the main consideration if you can't initialize at declaration. If something depends on a constructor declaration - use the constructor. If something depends on other things like property inputs, use componentWillLoad or wherever in the lifecycle as early as possible you can calculate the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Stencil Style Guide](https://stenciljs.com/docs/style-guide#component-ts-class-) you should initialize `@State` variables at declaration if you can:

```
  /**
   * 3. State() variables
   * Inlined decorator, alphabetical order.
   */
  @State() isValidated: boolean;
  @State() status = 0;
```